# Context-free grammar for ${a^n b^n a^n}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to figure out a formal grammar for the above language. This language describes palindromes, so it is context-free, if I am not wrong. I came up with a context-sensitive grammar, but I can not find a context-free one. Any ideas?

Comment: This language is not context free, so a context free grammar for it is impossible. It is a context sensitive language, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The languages of all palindromes  is context-free.

That does not implies that any language that contains only palindromes is context-free. For example, many language over the unary alphabet $\{a\}$ are not context-free. In fact, they can even be non-context-sensitive or undecidable. Note that any word over a unary alphabet is a palindrome.

In particular, the language of all words like $a^nb^na^n$ is not context-free. The rough intuition to understand why it is not context-free is that a PDA cannot remember two unbounded independent relations. You can either use the pumping lemma to prove that fact.

**Exercise.** Give an example of a unary language that is not context-free.

Comment: How about $\{a^{\Sigma(n)} \colon n \ge 1\}$, where $\Sigma$ is Radó's noncomputablr busy-beaver function?

Answer (score 0):

How about $\{a^{\Sigma(n)} \colon n \ge 1\}$, where $\Sigma$ is Radó's noncomputablr busy-beaver function?